# How boolean condition works in javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-statements

I am creating same if else function on my program. And I want to make it more short but same logic.

```
if(!checkStringInput("Test", 14)){
     elementHasError($element);
} else {
     elementIsOk($element);
}
```

I am thinking this boolean condition can be a shorter one to:

```
CONDITION ? FUNCTION1; : FUNCTION2;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why make it shorter when the code gets less readable (maintainable)?

Comment: @edHeal - Sorry for that. But that whole code is always using. For me, it is a bit messy and I want something more short if calling it 10 times on my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
!checkStringInput("Test", 14)) ? elementHasError($element) : elementIsOk($element);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am doing the wrong way on using this logic. I have ';' on both functions. Thank you for this information. Now it works.

Comment: Glad to help even if it some small ;)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the shortest possible:

```
(checkStringInput("Test", 14) ? elementIsOk : elementHasError)($element);
```

Comment: Well, you could omit a few whitespaces :-) Actually this even looks *clean*, +1!

Comment: I like this approach but it may cause issues when the handler needs to be called in some context. For example: `(checkStringInput("Test", 14) ? this.elementIsOk : this.elementHasError)($element);` Well in this case, conetxt gets lost. OP can use this as well because he does not need any context in the method.

Comment: @blunderboy `(checkStringInput("Test", 14) ? elementIsOk : elementHasError).call(this, $element);`

Comment: @Purrfection I know there are more alternatives to this (like bind). I just wanted to make a point to the readers. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
!checkStringInput("Test", 14)? elementHasError($element): elementIsOk($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have it correct. Were you looking for something else beyond the terniary operation?

`!checkStringInput('Test', 14) ?  elementHasError($element) :  elementIsOk($element);`